# asymmetric layout with margin on the left

Tags: margins, geometry, marginpar

The following MWE gives me a margin that is always on the right.
Is there a way to have the margin always on the **left**?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{geometry,lipsum}
\geometry{ 
    a4paper,
    left=24.8mm,
    top=27.4mm,
    headsep=2\baselineskip,
    textwidth=107mm,
    marginparsep=8.2mm,
    marginparwidth=49.4mm,
    textheight=49\baselineskip,
    headheight=\baselineskip,
    twoside,
    asymmetric,
  showframe,
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a wider inner width (e.g. `inner=70mm`) and use `\reversemarginpar` to print the margin text on the left.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{geometry,lipsum}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=24.8mm,
    top=27.4mm,
    inner=70mm,
    headsep=2\baselineskip,
    textwidth=107mm,
    marginparsep=8.2mm,
    marginparwidth=49.4mm,
    textheight=49\baselineskip,
    headheight=\baselineskip,
    twoside,
    asymmetric,
  showframe,
}

\reversemarginpar

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
Text
\marginpar{\lipsum}
\lipsum%
\end{document}
```